# SQL/PHP how to write WHERE which returns everything

Tags: php, sql

I have a PHP-Function which selects films from a SQL-Database using a procedure with a WHERE sorting:

```
drop procedure if exists editFilm;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE editFilm(
            IN inFilmId int,
            )
  BEGIN
  SELECT * from Film where FilmId = inFilmId
  END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now I want to have the possibility to set "everything" so all data gets replied as if the WHERE didn't exist.

I tryed using *, % and leaving it empty, but none of that works.

How can I give there WHERE a value which will return everything?

Comment: "as if the WHERE didn't exist"  And that's exactly what you do.  Just remove the clause.

Comment: If you want a placeholder, you can use `WHERE 1=1`.

Comment: @PatrickQ Yeah, but this would need a second query and an if in PHP which I personally don't like so much. Espacially with the provided code only being a sample and in reality it being a quite large procedure.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. But it is a procedure in SQL, so I can't change the FilmId = part. Only the input "1" itself

Comment: There's nothing you can put after `where FilmId = ` that will always match.

Comment: @Tim If you have limiting criteria, that should really be stated _in your question_.

Comment: Can you change it to `WHERE FilmID LIKE`? Then you can use `%` to match anything.

Comment: @PatrickQ I thought that would be clear

Comment: @Barmar That works! Great, thank you! Could you maybe provide it as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: @Tim There is no way we can assume what your environment is and what can and cannot be changed.  That information has to, and can only, come from you.  And for reference, even in the comments, you said "I can't change the FilmId = part".  But apparently you can, since you changed the "=" to "LIKE".  Please take care to be precise when describing your situation.  It will save you and us wasted time.

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes sorry. I meant I can't change = to like when I call the procedure. But I can change it in the procedure itself

Comment: @PatrickQ Normally it gets an Index as Integer value. So anything from 1 to a billion. I just tested it and if I enter 1, it only will show 1 not 1 and 10 so it perfectly works. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query to use `LIKE` rather than `=`. If the parameter does not contain any wildcard characters, SQL will treat this like `=`. But if you want to match everything, you can use the wildcard `'%'`.

Make sure that when you supply a parameter to the procedure that you escape wildcard characters with `\` if you want to do a normal equality test. In `LIKE` patterns, `%` and `_` are wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * from Film
WHERE FilmId = inFilmId
OR inFilmId IS NULL
  ;
```

---

Or, if you also want to *match all* on an empty string:

---

```
SELECT * from Film
WHERE FilmId = inFilmId
OR COALESCE(inFilmId, '') = ''
  ;
```

---

But, if your inFilmId is an integer, you could **invent** another *specialvalue*

---

```
SELECT * from Film
WHERE FilmId = inFilmId
OR COALESCE(inFilmId, -666) = -666
  ;
```